# How to sort a dictionary keys and pick the first in MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, projection

I'm running the following query as described in [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-the-specified-fields-and-the-_id-field-only).

```
db.getCollection('things')
  .find(
    { _id: UUID("...") },
    { _id: 0, history: 1 }
  )
```

It produces a single element that, when unfolded in the GUI, shows the dictonary *history*. When I unfold that, I get to see the contents: bunch of keys and correlated values.

Now, I'd like to sort the keys alphabetically and pick *n* first ones. Please note that it's not an array but a dictionary that is stored. Also, it would be great if I could flatten the structure and pop up my *history* to be the head (root?) of the document returned.

I understand it's about projection and slicing. However, I'm not getting anywhere, despite many attempts. I get syntax errors or a full list of elements. Being rather nooby, I fear that I require a few pointers on how to diagnose my issue to begin with.

Based on the comments, I tried with [`aggregate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) and [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-sort). Regrettably, I only seem to be sorting the current output (that produces a single document due to the match condition). I want to access the elements inside `history`.

```
db.getCollection('things')
  .aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: UUID("...") } },
    { $sort: { history: 1 } }
  ])
```

I'm sensing that I should use projection to pull out a list of elements residing under `history` but I'm getting no success using the below.

```
db.getCollection('things')
  .aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: UUID("...") } },
    { $project: { history: 1, _id: 0 } }
  ])
```

Comment: can you show an example document and the expected result from that document? the sorting is not possible in object in find query, you have to go with aggregation query.

Comment: @turivishal Not sure how to show an example (most likely due to my noobness with MongoDb). Sorry about that. What I mainly get stuck on, is how to access the elements that are stored in the field *history*. See the edit, as I switched to aggregation, as you suggested.

Comment: for ex. assume history field has in database like `history: { field1: "value", field2: "value" }`, if you want to select field1 only in history they use `history: { field1: 1 }` in projection, if you want to select field1 in root use `field1: "$history.field1"`.

Comment: @turivishal Ah, now we're getting somewhere! Partially, but still. Now, what if I don't know the names of the fields but want to pick the first one (after alphabetical sort, that is)? I'd like to perform a match, then sort the fields in `history` and pick, say 3 topmost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a long process to just sort object properties by alphabetical order,

- `$objectToArray` convert `history` object to array in key-value format
- `$unwind` deconstruct above generated array
- `$sort` by `history` key by ascending order (1 = ascending, -1 = descending)
- `$group` by `_id` and reconstruct `history` key-value array
- `$slice` to get your number of properties from dictionary from top, i have entered 1
- `$arrayToObject` back to convert key-value array to object format

```
db.getCollection('things').aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: UUID("...") } },
  { $project: { history: { $objectToArray: "$history" } } },
  { $unwind: "$history" },
  { $sort: { "history.k": 1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      history: { $push: "$history" }
    }
  },
  { 
    $project: { 
      history: { 
        $arrayToObject: { $slice: ["$history", 1] } 
      } 
    } 
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D7xYTAVwNW-)

---

There is another option, but as per MongoDB, it can not guarantee this will reproduce the exact result,

- `$objectToArray` convert `history` object to array in key-value format
- `$setUnion` basically this operator will get unique elements from an array, but as per experience, it will sort elements by key ascending order, so as per MongoDB there is no guarantee.
- `$slice` to get your number of properties from dictionary from top, i have entered 1
- `$arrayToObject` back to convert key-value array to object format

```
db.getCollection('things').aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: UUID("...") } },
  {
    $project: {
      history: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $slice: [
            { $setUnion: { $objectToArray: "$history" } },
            1
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/k18sBjpFmQc)

Comment: What's the significance of the ".k" in there? Is it just a temporary variable name or is it something specific to MongoDb that I'm not familiar with, yet?

Comment: the $objectToArray operator will produce `[{k: "field1", v: "value"}]` array from `{ field1: "value" }` dictionary, so it is easy to order by just name and `$arrayToObject` is an opposite of that. you can check the updated answer.

Comment: Your answer resolved my full issue in an excellent way. I realize that I wasn't even close and there's a few new pots in the docs to look into that I previously wasn't even aware of (e.g. `$unwind` operator). Really great info! Will I always get the document to unfold to see the history that I need to unfold to see the sliced out fields? Or is there a way to "flatten up" the result to only list the fields skipping history as a holder? I sense that it's got to do with projection as an additional stage but I'm not entirely certain...

Comment: yes you have to do this process, that option is accurate. I have added second option as well but mongodb will not guarantee to reproduce the expected result.